# How to get a list of official Docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I am trying to get a list of all the official images from the [Docker Store](http://store.docker.com). However, I could not find any simple way to get the list. Docker CLI has a `docker search` command but it does not have any argument to get 
 a list of all the images from the Docker Store and then filter it later.

Any ideas how it could be done?

Answer (score 4):

If you click the "explore" menu item at the top; https://store.docker.com/search?q=&source=verified&type=image all official images are shown. You can find *non* official images in the "Community (Docker Hub)" section.

[image: Docker Store explore options]

From the command-line, you can search using the `--filter is-official=true` filter option, for example:

```
docker search --filter is-official=true php
NAME             DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
php              While designed for web development, the PH...   2210      [OK]
php-zendserver   Zend Server - the integrated PHP applicati...   110       [OK]
```

Comment: Well, I am interested in command-line solution so that I can programmatically get complete list without going through docker store webpages. However, your solution require query term to be added such as 'php' in your case. I need something like a regex to get every image something like following.
`docker search --filter is-official=true *`

Comment: No, I don't think the current search API provided by Docker Hub and Docker Store have this. Can you explain the use case for showing _all_ images? It occurs to me that usuall you'd be looking for some image, so search for keyword?

Comment: I am doing a project where I am analyzing all the official images to find some specific packages. So I need the list of all the official images which I can docker pull in my script and later analyze them.

Comment: I don't think the search API is really intended for scraping Docker Hub. You could script searching for `a`, then searching for `b`, etc, then remove the duplicates.

Comment: I'd be interested in an API call for that, too. @Wajih have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use their api. the trick is replacing the `_` from the public url with `library`: https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions mentioned, you can list all images under the library user from the hub page (less programmatic than the hub API mentioned by [kpacha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582677/596285)):

https://hub.docker.com/u/library/

And there's also the upstream github repo:

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/tree/master/library